# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: :unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven, security

When I run

```
mvn clean install
```

command from command prompt I am getting the below error:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I already have cacerts.cer file in my
 **jdk\jdk1.8.0_25-windows-x64\jre\lib\security**

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you add the host's certificate to cacerts?

Comment: i generated the jssecacerts file.Is this what you mean?